# First Time Ethereum Wallet User Setup Questions

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

I will try to make this a fast post with just a few questions I cannot figure out the answers to:

I am trying to accept/send ETH payments and have downloaded, installed, and created a wallet using Ethereum Wallet 0.11.1.

I have my wallet created and address, but here are my noobie questions:

1) Does this Ethereum wallet accept ETH payments? (I saw something about ETC vs. ETH and I care about ETH)

2) What all does one need to send a payment? Just the user's Address hex?

3) When a payment is sent, how long does it typically take to reflect in the receiver's wallet?

4) Is there any risk of losing Ether funds if the wallet is unable or doesn't sync with the Network Node for say 1 week?

5) I understand with Ethereum Wallet there is a password (user-created) and keystore, but isn't there also supposed to be a private key to save/backup somewhere?

6) I'm confused about Ethereum ICO and something about ERC20 or other? I'm not really sure, but I just want to make sure I can accept ETH payments without issue using Ethereum Wallet 0.11.1.

Thank you so much any answers will really help put my mind at ease about getting into Ether transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Does this Ethereum wallet accept ETH payments? (I saw something about ETC vs. ETH and I care about ETH)

Yes it does, however it requires you to sync the blockchain before you can view balances.

> 2) What all does one need to send a payment? Just the user's Address hex?

Yes. In order to send ETH from one address to another, a sender needs the receiver's public address (which looks something like this: `0x4bbeEB066eD09B7AEd07bF39EEe0460DFa261520`) and enough ETH to send the amount being sent + the cost of ETH used for gas.

> 3) When a payment is sent, how long does it typically take to reflect in the receiver's wallet?

This depends on how the gas is configured by the user. Can be as fast as 15 seconds or as slow as forever. If you're using the Ethereum Wallet app it may take a long time to notice the changes if it isn't synced up, because the only way the Ethereum Wallet can see the changes are if it's up to date with the block number that the transaction was approved in.

> 4) Is there any risk of losing Ether funds if the wallet is unable or doesn't sync with the Network Node for say 1 week?

No. The way that the network works is that the funds are allocated to a public address (which is only accessible via the private key for that address) whenever funds are sent to that address. The funds don't exist in a wallet. They only exist on the blockchain. The wallet is just a software that generates and/or stores your private key which is how you "prove ownership" of the public address. The private key IS ownership of the public address. Funds will sit there (showing as in the public address of the receiver) until someone with a private key for that public address accesses it and sends it away to a different address.

> 5) I understand with Ethereum Wallet there is a password (user-created) and keystore, but isn't there also supposed to be a private key to save/backup somewhere?

The password in the Ethereum Wallet is used to encrypt the private key into the keystore file. The keystore file IS your encrypted private key. Using just a private key to access your account is considered insecure for most users. Because private keys ARE ownership of a public address, private key management is of the utmost importance in cryptocurrencies. Normally, people in the space would recommend purchasing a hardware wallet (such as a Ledger Nano S or a Trezor) for this reason. Hardware wallets don't require you to know your private key and they don't require you to expose your private key to the internet in order to interact with your Ethereum keypairs.

> 6) I'm confused about Ethereum ICO and something about ERC20 or other? I'm not really sure, but I just want to make sure I can accept ETH payments without issue using Ethereum Wallet 0.11.1.

ERC20 tokens are implementations of Ethereum code to generate a token with fixed supply. They don't really have anything to do if you just want to accept ETH payments. There is a bit of background reading for them, but you can start here if you're interested: https://cointelegraph.com/explained/erc-20-tokens-explained

I would recommend using a different software due to the complexities of key management and the current relative difficulty of using the standard Ethereum Wallet software and keeping your node up-to-date. Maybe look into MyCrypto or MyEtherWallet. And definitely, at least look into the purchase of a hardware wallet if you're planning to store more than a few hundred dollars worth of ETH/ERC20 tokens. The cryptocurrency ecosystem is rife with scams that target both individuals and vast swathes of cryptocurrency users, so I can't overstate how important it is that you read up on how to secure your funds.

Comment: You are an AMAZING person!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so incredibly much you've helped me and hopefully others that stumble across this more than you know!!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does this Ethereum wallet accept ETH payments? (I saw something about ETC vs. ETH and I care about ETH)

Yes.

> 2) What all does one need to send a payment? Just the user's Address hex?

Just the address (hex).

> 3) When a payment is sent, how long does it typically take to reflect in the receiver's wallet?

It depends on the gas price (transaction fee) that was used. Miners will 'mine' transactions with a high gas price first. You can use a tool like [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) to get a rough estimation on how long a transaction will take based on the gas price.

> 4) Is there any risk of losing Ether funds if the wallet is unable or doesn't sync with the Network Node for say 1 week?

No, as long as you have your private key you can access your funds. Your balance is stored in the blockchain, so even if your client is not in sync, your ETH remain safe in your wallet. If you want you can even use a different wallet application, import your private key and access your funds from there.

> 5) I understand with Ethereum Wallet there is a password (user-created) and keystore, but isn't there also supposed to be a private key to save/backup somewhere?

The keystore file contains your private key, encrypted by the password. If you keep a safe backup of your keystore file and password you can use those to recover your private key.

> 6) I'm confused about Ethereum ICO and something about ERC20 or other? I'm not really sure, but I just want to make sure I can accept ETH payments without issue using Ethereum Wallet 0.11.1.

[ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) is a token standard for tokens that don't use their own network. Token developers can distribute these tokens using an Initial Coin Offering (ICO), where the user sends an amount of ETH to the token contract and gets a number of newly created tokens back.

If you just want to receive ETH payments, you don't have to worry about ERC-20 or ICOs.